# Programmatic Modal View Popup Swift 4 Confusion

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

For my project I needed to implement custom popups for a user to interact with. In order to get the popup to display correctly I had to create a UIView, set it's bounds to the desired size, and add it to the presented modal view controller's subviews. I could not resize immediate view of the modal view controller, and ended up having to set it's background color to clear as it always displayed full screen despite setting .modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext. My fix feels like a hack, can someone explain to me why my initial approach didn't work?